# How to separate but not split a data frame by differences in value between different rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame of genetic loci, and I'm trying to group it by gene based on similar start-end values. The difference between the end values between rows should not exceed 2000, for example, to be counted as the same gene.

[Example Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQxGE.png)

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 5000 | 6000 |
| 12000 | 13000 |

These should constitute two different genes.

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 37000 | 38000 |
| 38500 | 39000 |

These should be the same genes.

I have tried splitting the data frame by creating an index of end value differences and using cumsum(). The program stalls.

`index <- c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(df$End)) > 2000))`
`geneList <- split(df, index)`

This should return a list of data frames with similar start-end values.

What I'd like to do, ideally, is to be able to break up the data frame into intervals similar to the cut function without having to create entirely new data frames. Then, I'd be able to do work within each interval. I believe that this would work with the split function, but the program seems to stall. I believe this is due to the large amount of data I am working with.

Comment: Provide One dataframe, and then a column of ID showing how they are grouped with the logic behind the ID column. So far you have provided 2 dataframes

Comment: @onyambu These are the same data frame, just at different rows. These are also the only IDs.

Comment: First, yes I can tell its the same dataframe, but you have it separated into two. Second, there is no ID column. Show an ID column that separates the rows. ie `1,1,2,2` to show that the first two rows are together and the next two rows are together. Then provide the logic as to how you want the ID column to be created

Comment: Could you more explicitly define "similar start-end values"? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?
If so, I'd be happy to explain the working of dthe code below.

```
library(data.table)
library(intervals)

DT <- fread("Start  End
            5000    6000
            12000   13000
            37000   38000
            38500   39000")


gap = 2000

DT.int <- as.data.table(
  intervals::close_intervals( 
    intervals::contract( 
      intervals::reduce( 
        intervals::expand( 
          intervals::Intervals(as.matrix(DT), type = "Z" ), 
          gap/2)
        ), 
      gap/2)
    )
  )
DT.int[, id := .I]
      
# join back the id
DT[DT.int, id := i.id, on = .(Start >= V1, End <= V2)][]

   Start   End id
1:  5000  6000  1
2: 12000 13000  2
3: 37000 38000  3
4: 38500 39000  3
```

Comment: OP needs a factor to group the rows of the data, ie like the `cut` function. The first two rows are in different groups while the last two are in the same group. ie something whose labels will be `1,2,3,3`. OP does not need to subset the data

Comment: yes.. but with these intervals you can easily perform a join to get the interval numbering to the original dataset. See the edited answer